enclosure case and commands windows for hdd
My enclosures case USB 3.0 models Orico 25PW1 black and Kesu 2530 uses the ASM235CM or JMicron generic JMS578 chips. Do these two chips have full support to pass on all commands and signals from Windows to safely eject and remove hardware to park the 2.5" HDD heads even without disconnecting the USB cable from the enclosure and PC?
Does the brand, model, chip and firmware of the USB 3.0 enclosure case interfere with these processes of sending signals and commands from Windows to the 2.5" HDD?

You have already asked a question here about the heads being parked when a drive is ejected (Windows 10 IIRC). It was definitely not Retrocomputing (anything with USB 3 is likely not retrocomputing). You have also asked on Super User about this multiple times, and it remains unclear to me what information you're actually looking for, or what the problem you're facing is.

I'm pretty sure all drives built after around 1995 park their heads automatically when powered off. None of the older ones have an USB 3.0 interface.

what Stack Exchange community is good for post for enclosure usb3.0 and hdd parking technical questions?

Why would you think 'retrocomputing' wants questions about current systems?  On the other hand, you have asked several disk-related questions in 'superuser', which seem to get answered. That seems more appropriate.

And this question is essentially a repost of a question that you asked in a comment on superuser, two days ago.  Please don't cross-post.

@classicsamusaran You already posted the same or similar question about modern USB3 HDD cases before. You were told it was off topic. It has not changed since. Please do not ask this question here again.
